# Flatten directed, acyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Suppose I have a directed, acyclic graph where $A \to B$ represents that $A$ depends on $B$.

I want to 'flatten' this graph so that each vertex has an edge to all direct and indirect dependencies. Ie. create a new graph such that if $A \to B$ and $B \to C$ in the original graph, then the new graph will contain $A \to B$, $B \to C$, and $A \to C$.

What is the proper name for this operation, and are there existing algorithms that can perform this task?

Comment: You want the *transitive closure* of the digraph. Not posting a full answer as I don't know about any good algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for that. In case anybody else needs information about algorithms in future, this thesis provides a good starting point (https://www.cs.hut.fi/~enu/thesis.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *transitive closure graph* (or sometimes *reachability graph*) and can be implemented in nearly all graph software.  In *Mathematica*:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
   4 \[DirectedEdge] 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
TransitiveClosureGraph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]